# +ubuntu +20.04 lsdvd "libdvdread: Could not open /dev/dvd with libdvdcss."

Tags: mount, dvd

Ubuntu 20.04 only reads the DVD drive intermittently.

When it fails, it is accompanied by a short "brrrzzzt" buzz a few times immediately after a disc is inserted (and it happens on different discs) after which it is silent.

Sometimes the eject-button press on the drive is ignored although the 'eject' command never fails. ('eject -t' works as well.)

At other times, not always requiring a reboot, the drive will behave normally, even with a disc it had failed to read earlier.

All of "libdvd*" packages are reported to be up-to-date by apt install:
libdvd-pkg
libdvdcss
libdvdcss-dev
libdvdnav4
libdvdnav-dev
libdvdread7
libdvdread-dev
ubuntu-restricted-extras

Incidentally, attempts to install libdvdnav and libdvdread resulted in "Unable to locate pkg" errors (making me wonder if there are links missing somewhere...)

I have, in fact, replaced the DVD drive with a new one, BUT had assumed its own intermittent behavior was a result of old age. It is possible that whatever-the-problem-is was already in play then.

The same intermittent difficulty in recognition is also encountered with an external USB DVD drive is attached.

Having installed the lsdvd package, it reports:
% lsdvd
libdvdread: Could not open /dev/dvd with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open /dev/dvd for reading
Can't open disc /dev/dvd!

Answer (score 0):

My internal cd/dvd drive was becoming buggy on my Lenovo-ideapad-300-17ISK laptop, so I bought an LG external cd/dvd drive today (model SP80). I expected problems after losing my last fight with getting a Brother scanner/printer to scan and send the image to my laptop. I ended up bringing in a Windows 7 laptop as a workaround, and so I was prepared for disappointment with the new external cd/dvd drive. The new external cd/dvd drive would light up and spin when I put in a DVD, but it would quit without launching my default media player, VLC. I was not sure that my Ubuntu 20.04.02 laptop was even recognizing the new drive. So, I searched the Internet and found some terminal commands for displaying information about the available drives, and I so I set up to execute the commands after starting the new drive again, and I don't think the new drive showed up, but rather only the old internal drive. I thought, 'maybe a less demanding file format might make it through since some posts indicated that audio files got through.'
So, I tried again, but the audio file may have been DRM protected, so I tried a simple no-DRM audio disk (.wav files) and it worked. It took quite a while for VLC to open up and start playing the disk. Even then, it felt wrong because the new drive kept starting and stopping. It felt cheap. Perceptions aside, that may be how they all work, and I just didn't notice before. Some of the Internet posts mentioned that the external drives need to be mounted, and the posts suggested using the default program called "disks." The "disks" utility can apparently be used to mount both files/partitions and media devices, such as my new drive, and my old internal drive is in fact listed in "Disks" as being in dev/sr0 as a directory location. I was hesitant to just follow the instructions in Internet posts for mounting my new drive without understanding anything (though I have done that before), so I wanted to see more information. I set up "Disks" to launch, and then I restarted my new drive (plugging it into the USB anew), and voila! my new drive showed listed in "Disks." However, it, too, has the same directory location as the old drive, dev/sr0, and that bothers me. How are the different drives going to be distinguished under the hood if they do not have separate final directories? The only drive with a disc in it may be enough, but some of the Internet posts talked about creating a new final directory for the new drive. However, given how API's may work in VLC, I am not comfortable with creating my own previously unknown directory and hoping that other programs will correctly find it. This all looks nuts to me. As an aside, I noticed later that when I first plug in the new drive with a DVD in it, the title of the movie briefly appeared in small text, and then disappeared, but I am now having trouble recreating that, although I think that it was briefly appearing in the top bar of VLC. That told me that the movie is available and is being read initially, but something breaks down from there. I don't have the solution to your problem, but I thought that it might help you by seeing how I am approaching it.

Comment: Indeed it does help to see what you've tried. Ubuntu 20.04 does not have a program called "disks" nor does apt/aptitude offer a package approximating that name.  Could you clarify how you accessed it? Back in my Windows Daze I would have "uninstalled" the DVD drive in the hardware manager and let it "find it" again to see if a config error had crept in.